# Music of My Hero Academia season 2 episode 22

Tags: music, my-hero-academia

I’ve been having trouble finding this one track and it’s driving me INSANE. It happens when yaoyorozu is tracked down by Aizawa, and the timestamps are about: 13:04 to about 13:57. Any help would be appreciated, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

This is ***The Threat of Offence and Defense*** (脅威との攻防, *Kyōi to no kōbō*), the 29th track from *My Hero Academia Original Soundtrack*.

YouTube link: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=bwtMpGBBq9I&list=PLPaN6Wrl_xE09LFKm7Bwm1qeOZ-Kmgyz3&index=29